# Facebook will not allow me to post to a user's wall without a dialog. How can causes.com get away with it?

Tags: facebook

I have an app that allows users to share the page to specific users by clicking on check boxes next to their name and then doing a bunch of posts. I received an alert in February that said I would not be able to post to friends' walls unless there is a dialog box.

However, I noticed if you sign a petition on Causes.com, they do something very similar where they post the petition to a bunch of friends' walls.

I'm curious how they get away with that. Maybe I'm not familiar enough with the Facebook API.

Comment: Maybe causes.com got the same notice?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this helps, but Facebook does have business partnerships with certain sites/companies that have more privileges to their api keys, facebook app. This could be one of these instances.

One instance of this is, when you go to a major site and the site is able to read your facebook session, and within that site they show your name and picture once the site is rendered. In essence, these sites already know who you are.